# Remove all *.mp4 and *.zip but some files

Tags: bash, shell, rm

In one of my programs I call a `bash` command to remove all files in the directory, but some:

```
bash -c
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s nullglob
rm /path/to/directory/!("file1" | "file2")
```

Which for what I understand mean "Use bash on this command, use the extended pattern, remove all files but those"

It works good, but deletes every file but the ones put in the command.

What I would like is to remove all .mp4 and .zip in the directory but the ones I put in the command.

I think I'll have to add *.mp4 and *.zip somewhere in the command, but I have no idea where.

EDIT: For clarity, what I need is
"Delete all .mp4 and .zip files, but keep thoses"

Comment: have you tried `rm /path/to/directory/{*.zip,*.mp4}`?

Comment: Bashism... Bleah. Use find and learn how to make it portable between various system. Why would one need to use bash for such simple goal?

Comment: I am trying with `rm /path/to/directory/{*.zip, *.mp4, !("file1" | "file2")`

Comment: @Anthon I get `rm: missing operand`

Comment: @Jiri: Because the app is not meant to be portable. Is there other way to delete a file on raspbian?

Comment: It's not about your app is not portable. It's about good behaviour. World is not only bash/Linux. Use the strength of bash when it makes really sense but this is not the case. Maybe one day you would sit in front of Solaris, *BSD, AIX... Then what? It's nothing more stupid than bash-based shebang when it is not needed.

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha: And at that moment I ll learn and use equivalent  on whatever else system, I only use bash because my full app is in node.js, but I need a quick way to purge all unused files, and the fastest way I found is to use bash.

Comment: @DrakaSAN missing operand means there are no files with that pattern, you probably already deleted them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `!("file1" | "file2")` matches any file except `file1␣` or `␣file2` where `␣` is a space. The way you quoted it is misleading: it's equivalent to `!(file1 | file2)` or `!("file1 "|" file2`)`.

There's no way in bash to combine a negative pattern with a positive pattern to say “all of these except for those”. In zsh, you can write

```
setopt extended_glob
rm /path/to/directory/*.(mp4|zip)~(keep*|1234.zip)
```

to remove `this.mp4` and `that.zip` but not `keep-this.mp4` or `1234.zip`.

In bash, you can set the [`GLOBIGNORE` variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) to exclude certain patterns from all matches.

```
shopt -s extglob
GLOBIGNORE='keep*:1234.zip'
rm /path/to/directory/*.(mp4|zip)
unset GLOBIGNORE
```

Alternatively, you can use `find`, which lets you build arbitrarily complex boolean expressions.

```
find /path/to/directory \( -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.zip' \) ! -name 'keep*' ! -name '1234.zip' -delete
```

Note that `find` recurses into subdirectories. If this isn't desired, add `-maxdepth 1` after `/path/to/directory`.

If your `find` doesn't understand `-maxdepth` (it's common but not standard), use `-type d -prune -o` instead. If your `find` doesn't understand `-delete` (same remark), use `-exec rm {} +` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways:

- Use find (portable as it does not need specific shell [bash])

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name "exclude" -delete
```

or in case you have several patterns:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! \( -name "exclude" -o -name "exclude2" \) -exec rm -f {} \+
```

- Use GLOBIGNORE variable (bash only)

```
export GLOBIGNORE=exclude:exclude1:mask*
```

That will exclude mentioned files and masks from globing.
After that you can specify `rm your_pattern`

You can try it before with `ls`

Comment: missing closing bracket

Comment: GNUism. Please be more general and use either 'exec rm' or 'xargs rm'. Thanks.

Comment: I m trying it right now, but it seems it will find all files but thoses I exclude, what I need is to find all .mp4 and .zip but thoses I want to exclude.

Comment: For find, where is supposed to be the `)`? (several pattern)

Comment: @DrakaSAN you can use something like `find . -name *.ext ! -name 1.ext`

Answer (score 0):

I would you find. However your problem is the spaces.

`rm /path/to/directory/!("file1" | "file2")`

is the same as 
`rm "/path/to/directory/!(file1" "|" "file2)"`

not
`rm "/path/to/directory/!(file1|file2)"`

read up on the shell quoting rules.